# Same Guid for same prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, client-server, guid

I have a client-server module and I send the server state to the client using JSON (some transforms data). Additionally, I have a save and load system. I am using Guid for ID ( Guid.NewGuid().ToString() ). What I want to do is that, Is there any way to generate the same Id for the same prefab or how can do this. Basically, when I send the Guid and transforms to the client, based on Guid, the client can assign correct transforms to prefabs. I couldn't generate the same Guid for the same prefabs. Btw, I have two separate git projects for the client and server.

Comment: You could generate and assign the GUID in a serialized field when you create these prefabs ... Why do you use two different projects for client and server?

Comment: As per the project, there is a server and more than one client. The server is assigning the GUID as you said, but I want to be able to create the same GUID on both the client and the server with a script.

Comment: Well as you say these are two independent projects so there is no script that can assign things to both ... Alternatively create everything on the server, assign the GUIDs and then export your prefabs with the assigned and serialized ID to a [unitypackge](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html) and import that into the client project ...

Comment: I see what you mean but I need to transfer with json